# Touchscreen file browser suitable for conference room? Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, touchscreen

Hi I was wondering is there a preexisting piece of software (free or paid) that would allow people attending an event to browse content like photos, pdfs and video on a touchscreen. It needs to prevent them from clicking off the filebrowser onto the desktop etc.

I tried modifying the homescreen on a lenovo touchscreen running windows 8 but it doesn't seem very intuitive to people who have never used windows 8 before.